# In typescript, how to restrict a typing reference to a certain file?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to cleanly write some universal javascript code, for node and browser.

Most of the code is env-agnostic, however, some implementation parts detect the environment (node or browser) and conditionally execute different code.

I would like to activate node typings **ONLY** for those specific files. However, I couldn't find a way to do so. Either:

- node typings, when referenced in even one file only, are made effective for all files (bad, since I could inadvertently rely on node specificities)
- if not referencing node typings at all, typescript obviously complains about a lot of unknown definitions, which would be painful to patch by hand

Do anyone has a clean way of activating some type definitions for a selected set of files ?

Comment: Are you writing the definitions or using definitions supplied by someone else?  If you are writing your definitions and you write them as an [external module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) then you shouldn't be populating the global namespace with anything and you won't even need references.  Instead the client files would need imports similar to `import { Foo, Blah } from 'bar-module'` in any file they wanted to use `Foo` or `Blah` in and those imports would be file scoped.

Comment: Sorry, just was rethinking this comment and you should still need references.  The rest of the comment is still valid though.

Comment: @Pace I'm explicitely speaking about node.js typings, which I didn't write, and which are global...

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible at this time.

A solution: building node-dependant and node-independant files separately. This could be done automatically with a script.